# Copy paste row with timestamp for archiving purpose

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking on how to create a VBA code to copy and paste a row to archive sheet with timestamp.

```
Sub Archiving()
    Dim lr2 As Long
    Dim y As Worksheet, z As Worksheet
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim dt As String, wbNam As String

    Set y = Sheets("asheet")
    Set z = Sheets("archivesheet")

    lr2 = y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")

    'Here you select the range of your sheet you want to copy, for me is A:E
    Set copyRng = y.Range("A2:J" & lr2)

    z.Range("A2:J" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    copyRng.Copy z.Range("A2")
```

I have "A-Sheet" have 'A1' to 'B3'
How to copy to "B-Sheet", it shall copy to 'A1' to 'B3' but have with 'C' with current timestamp ?

And if I run the command how to make this continue copy from the next available row (A3) .

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong with your code? Were do you get errors and which? What does your code actually do vs. what do you expect? • Please clarify in your original question (not in a comment).

Comment: what is your question? What is your code doing and where does is fail to do what it should

Comment: It works to copy paste but I'm not sure how to add timestamp and how to continue only in next available row not replace the existing cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, this will add your timestamp to every row you copy on Column K, I've also altered your formatting of the timestamp to show the year as you would expect it to, from `yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm` to `yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm`:

I would also suggest you name your variables in a way that they identify what type of data they hold, such as below:

```
Sub Archiving()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet: Set wsFrom = Sheets("asheet")
    Dim wsTo As Worksheet: Set wsTo = Sheets("archivesheet")
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim TimeStamp As String

    LastRow = wsFrom.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row with data on Column E

    TimeStamp = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") 'format the timestampt

    Set copyRng = wsFrom.Range("A2:J" & LastRow) 'set your copy range

    wsTo.Range("A2:K" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert rows into sheet before pasting data

    copyRng.Copy wsTo.Range("A2") 'paste data into newly inserted empty rows

    wsTo.Range("K2:K" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Value = TimeStamp 'add timestampt to copied range
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

To paste as values I would amend the following line `copyRng.Copy wsTo.Range("A2")` as below:

```
copyRng.Copy 
wsTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: @zzz-zzz I've just made a slight change to the code, so when inserting the blank cells it also pushes down the timestamp, I believe this is what you meant, I've tested this running the code twice and it works as I would expect it to. Please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: example I run for the 1st time it will copy "A2:J" and have TimeStamp in "K" . 2nd time I run it succesfully copy to the next available row "A:J" doesn't have TimeStamp in the "K" . What I hope is everytime the command run, it will continously copy to the last available row and with timestamp on when the command done .

Comment: @zzz-zzz please try the code once more as I've altered it to correct the issue you are describing, it should now work as you would expect it to. :)

Comment: great ! it works like a charm, now I will just modify to copy by certain column field only . will post another question if found difficulties  . Thanks a lot .

Comment: how to make it paste as value ? i tried in other sheet and its paste including the formula ?

Comment: @zzz-zzz Please see my updated answer to paste as values. Hope this helps! :)